# Contour plot of a function of 3 variables

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, contour, figure

As we can make contour plot of `f=(x.^2) + (y.^2);` in 2-D as follows:

```
[x,y]= meshgrid(-10:10, -10:10);
contour(x,y, (x.^2)+(y.^2));
```

and we can make contour plot of `f=(x.^2) + (y.^2);` in 3-D using `contour3`

Can we make contour plot of `f=(x.^2) + (y.^2) + (z.^2);` in 3-D

Comment: [`contour3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour3.html)

Comment: [`scatter3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#btr5_il-1) where your color is `f`

Comment: @excaza !
`scatter3` is useful after the contours are made!
`contour3` can be used for contour plot of `f=(x.^2) + (y.^2);` , not when f is a function of 3 variables!

or can you elaborate it with an example?

Comment: you are talking about `isosurface` here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matlab function `isosurface` can do what you are asking. However you can also achieve the results you want using other alternatives, like using `surf`. I will cover both methods.

### Method 1: Using [`isosurface`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html)

We need to create the domain for `x`, `y` and `z` and then generate a 3D mesh with those values so that we can evaluate the function `f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2`. Then, we shall give a value to the constant `k` and feed all this information to `isosurface`, so that we can obtain the family of `(x,y,z)` values that satisfy the condition: `f(x,y,z) = k`. Note that this contours are in fact spheres! Finally we can use `patch` to generate a surface with those values.

It is very interesting to give different values for `k` iterativelly and see the contours associated with those values.

```
% Value for x, y and z domain.
a = 10;

% Domain for x ,y and z.
x = linspace(-a,a);
y = linspace(-a,a);
z = linspace(-a,a);

% Generate a 3D mesh with x, y and z.
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(x,y,z);

% Evaluate function (3D volume of data).
f = x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2;

% Do contours from k = 0 to k = 100 in steps of 1 unit.
for k = 0:100
    % Draw the contour that matches k.
    p = patch(isosurface(x,y,z,f,k));
    isonormals(x,y,z,f,p)
    p.FaceColor = 'red';
    p.EdgeColor = 'none';

    % Adjust figure properties.
    title(sprintf('Contours of f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2\nwith f(x,y,z) = k = %d',k));
    xlabel('x-axis');
    ylabel('y-axis');
    zlabel('z-axis');
    axis equal;
    grid on;
    box on;
    axis([-10 10 -10 10 -10 10]);
    camlight left;
    lighting phong;

    % Update figure.
    drawnow;

    % Clear axes.
    cla;
end
```

This is the output:

[image: Contours for f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 with isosurface]

### Method 2: Using [`surf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)

As in the previous method, to contour the function `f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2`, we need to match the function to a constant value, this is `f(x,y,z) = k`, where `k` is any constant value you choose.

If we isolate `z` in terms of `k`, `x` and `y` we have: `z = ± sqrt(k-x.^2-y.^2)`, so we have the explicit values for `x`, `y` and `z`. Now, let's give different values for `k` iterativelly and see the results that we get with the `surf` function!

```
% Do contours from k = 0 to k = 100 in steps of 1 unit.
for k = 0:100
    % Find the value where: k - x^2 - y^2 = 0
    a = sqrt(k);

    % Domain for x and y.
    x = linspace(-a,a);
    y = linspace(-a,a);
    [x,y] = meshgrid(x, y);

    % Isolate z in terms of k, x and y.
    z = sqrt(k-x.^2-y.^2);

    % Find complex entries in z.
    i = find(real(z)~=z);

    % Replace complex entries with NaN.
    z(i) = NaN;

    % Draw upper hemisphere of surface.
    surf(x,y,z,'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none');
    hold on;
    % Draw lower hemisphere of surface.
    surf(x,y,-z,'FaceColor','red','EdgeColor','none');

    % Adjust figure properties.
    title(sprintf('Contours of f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2\nwith f(x,y,z) = k = %d',k));
    xlabel('x-axis');
    ylabel('y-axis');
    zlabel('z-axis');
    axis equal;
    grid on;
    box on;
    axis([-10 10 -10 10 -10 10]);
    camlight left;
    lighting phong;

    % Update figure.
    drawnow;
    hold off;
end
```

This is the output:

[image: Contours for f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 with surf]

---

**References**

I took some of the ideas from [David Arnold's article](http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math50c/matlab/complex/index.xhtml) *"Complex Numbers and Plotting in Matlab"*, which is well worth a read and will help you understand how to plot functions that generate complex numbers.